# SQL check whether current date is monday

Tags: sql, firebird

I am trying to create a SQL statement in where clause so when the current date is a Monday, it returns Friday results, but if it is any other weekday, it returns yesterday as the result.

Something like this:

```
WHERE
---IS MONDAY ?
---THEN 
DATE = 'FRIDAY'

---IS TUESDAY,WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY OR  FRIDAY ?
---THEN
DATE = 'YESTERDAY'
```

How can I accomplish that using IIF or CASE?

Comment: Have you tried the [documentation](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-intfunc-extract.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firebird, you can use [`EXTRACT()`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-extract):

```
WHERE EXTRACT(WEEKDAY FROM my_date) = 1
```